# Corona SDK physics body based on image

Tags: lua, coronasdk, physics

I need create a lot of custom physics bodies and this is a bad way if I will create custom borders manually. Is there a way to create physics body based on some image or mask? The images are very complexly, so I can't use body based on the outline.

Comment: there are tools for that, ie PhysicsEditor I believe is compatible with Corona

Comment: If you are referring to their appearance then the physics module is not relevant, it just creates physics bodies from display objects. Did I misunderstand?